# Can't connect to PostgreSQL database on Heroku using Ruby - could not translate host name

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, pg

I'm using Ruby (not Rails) and connecting a PostgreSQL database. I've been trying to get set up on Heroku, but I'm having problems starting the application. Running the application locally works fine.

My local .env looks like:

```
postgres://DATABASE_URL=localhost
```

And the Ruby connect to connect to the database looks like:

```
@@db = PGconn.open(:hostaddr => ENV['DATABASE_URL'], :dbname => '(dbname)', :password => '(password)')
```

When I push to Heroku the app crashes on that line, and writes this error to the logs:

```
could not translate host name "postgres://(my heroku db address)" to address: Name or service not known (PG::Error)
```

The database address there matches the `DATABASE_URL` in my `heroku:config`. I'm using a shared database.

I tried using `:host => ENV['DATABASE_URL']` (as opposed to `:hostaddr`) but had the same result. I'm guessing there's something simple I'm missing but I haven't had any good ideas.

Comment: I'm hesitant to post the heroku db address because it contains a username and password. It's in the format postgres://(foo)@(bar).compute-1.amazonaws.com/ddnhsdgpcy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to parse out the specific parts of the `DATABASE_URL`. Please see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack#database_access

Answer (score 5):

Heroku's Devcenter doesn't appear to include this anymore, so here's how to do the split manually:

```
  db_parts = ENV['DATABASE_URL'].split(/\/|:|@/)
  username = db_parts[3]
  password = db_parts[4]
  host = db_parts[5]
  db = db_parts[7]
  conn = PGconn.open(:host =>  host, :dbname => db, :user=> username, :password=> password)
```

Courtesy [Grio](http://blog.grio.com/2013/06/how-to-create-a-rake-cron-job-in-heroku.html).