# Remote connect to Heroku pg database error: could not translate host name to address

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, activerecord, database-connection

I am trying to connect to my Heroku hosted postgres database but unfortunately it is returning a "failed to translate host name to address" error. I directly take the DATABASE_URL from heroku as shown in the establish_connection block below

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter    => "postgresql",
    :host       => `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -amy_app`,
    :database   => "my_db", 
    :username       => "postgres",
    :password   => "password")
```

The trace of the error is:

```
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize': could not
 translate host name "postgres://address_to_db.1.amazonaws.com:5432/ (PG::Connecti
onBad)
" to address: Unknown server error
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initializ
e'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql
_connection'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new
_connection'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `che
ckout_new_connection'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acq
uire_connection'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `blo
ck in checkout'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `che
ckout'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `blo
ck in connection'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `con
nection'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `ret
rieve_connection'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:93:in `columns'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:98:in `columns_hash'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:64:in `block in valid?'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:64:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:64:in `all?'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:64:in `valid?'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
```

After looking into it I found this solution to the problem

```
db_parts = ENV['DATABASE_URL'].split(/\/|:|@/)
username = db_parts[3]
password = db_parts[4]
host = db_parts[5]
db = db_parts[7]
```

from: [Can't connect to PostgreSQL database on Heroku using Ruby - could not translate host name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380438/cant-connect-to-postgresql-database-on-heroku-using-ruby-could-not-translate)

when I do this I instead receive a NoDatabaseError. I have manually entered the db name without any success. It is unclear to me as to whether this means it managed to find the database.

Does anyone have an idea of how to resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I have no managed to connect by running `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -amy_app` and reading the pre url "connection information" into the individual fields manually. It is unclear as to why a) only the url is returned when the request is made through a ruby system call. b) why it doesn't work using the split method

Tl;dr: Heroku's documentation doesn't explain how to connect to your app's database remotely or at least their documentation implies that the host should be the full DATABASE_URL.

Thanks,
SOliver

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to the server using a GUI client (like PSequel) to see if the database is indeed there.
If it's not, do

```
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can connect to the database using `heroku pg:psql` and the app itself connects to the database.

Comment: so I suppose you did a "heroku run rake db:migrate". Can you do it again and see what the output is?

Comment: There's no migrations waiting, I ran several a couple of days ago and they all processed correctly. I've manually split the "connection information" section of heroku config:get DATABASE_URL and it appears to now be connecting.

Heroku's documentation doesn't discuss this so I'll email them, hopefully they can tell users they need to split the URL up.

Comment: Good luck with this further